# how to reduce the width of table view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hii every one

how dod i reduce the width of the table view cell?

i am using following code to increase the height of the row ,, in the same way how can i alter width of the cell

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch(indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            switch(indexPath.row)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    return 100;
                }
                    break;

                case 1:
                {
                    return 40;
                }
                    break;

                case 2:
                {
                    return 40;
                }
                    break;

                case 3:
                {
                    return 40;
                }
                    break;

                default:
                {
                    return 15;
                }

            }
        }
            break;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned a cell will always have the same width, if however you wish to indent the content to show a master-detail relationship then use...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: what this method body contains,,only returns integer or any thing else, can u please elaborate

Comment: You return just an integer, but it tells the tableview how much to indent the content... see the following... http://pds19.egloos.com/pds/201007/07/99/e0000099_4c34229b67ae0.jpg

Answer (score 1):

An UITableViewCell will always take the full width of the UITableView that is displaying the cell.